# Calculating probabilities using cox regression

Tags: regression, predictive-models, survival, cox-model

I have done a multivariate Cox regression in R. The model fits to my data very well.

Now, I would like to use my model and predict the survival probabilities of new observations. I am unclear how to do this with a Cox model. Something similar to what can be done using a  logistic regression,to plugin the values of new observations and multiply them with betas and calculate the probabilities.

How can this be done in a Cox model?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `survfit` function in the survival package on a coxph object then it will provide the predicted survival function (at the specified set of covariates).  You can print or plot the entire function.  Also from the `survfit.object` you can calculate the proportion surviving at time points of interest.